# Json invalid for perl but ok for jq

Tags: json, perl

Why does the following string passes as JSON with jq but not with perl?
Example:

```
$ cat dummy.json | jq '.'  
{  
  "field": {  
    "customer_id": "abc"  
  },    
  "result": "processed"  
}
```

But with perl fails:

```
$ cat dummy.json | perl -MData::Dumper -MJSON=decode_json -ne'print decode_json($_)'  
, or } expected while parsing object/hash, at character offset 1 (before "\n") at -e line 1.
```

What am I messing up here?

Answer (score 8):

The decoder works fine, but you're only reading one line.

Slurp the file with [`perl -0777`](http://p3rl.org/run#-0[octal/hexadecimal])…

Comment: What is `-0777`? Can you elaborate? I don't get it

Comment: That's a hyperlink up there. Do follow it.

Comment: Ohhh, the new perldoc website. Sweet. :)